# microsoft pubcenter ads not responding to tap or click

Tags: c#, xaml, ads

I am developing a windows phone app with XAML and C# using visual studio 2013. I added a UI:AdControl as follows:

.....

```
xmlns:UI="using:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
```

.....

```
<UI:AdControl AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60" ApplicationId="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" AdUnitId="00000000" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="480" IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"/>
```

(the ApplicationId and AdUnitId are correct in the app but not shown here)

Adds are showing up correctly but when the tap on the ad it does not go to the advertiser's page as it does on a tablet and in other apps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `AdControl` not work you can use `ad mediation`. As per Microsoft-

> Microsoft provides support for ad mediation to let you optimize your
>   in-app advertising revenue by mediating ad requests from one or more
>   ad networks.
>
> Different ad networks which offer SDKs for displaying ads
>   in your Windows Phone app may have their own strengths, with some
>   having a higher cost per thousand views (eCPM) or higher fill rate
>   (percentage of ads served when your app makes a request) in certain
>   markets than others. With a single ad network, you may end up with
>   unfilled ad requests, causing you to lose potential revenue.

References

[1. Using ad mediation to maximize ad revenue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn864359.aspx)

[2. Downloaded the extension](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=518026)

[3. Inside Windows Platform: Maximize ad revenue with Windows Ad Mediator Service and Control](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/11/11/inside-windows-platform-maximize-ad-revenue-with-windows-ad-mediator-service-and-control/)

Comment: Ad mediation works. But this alternative not solution of the problem.  But i accept right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your z-index ordering, your AdControl may be being 'covered' by another control.

If the ads are displayed it's fundamentally working so if you have no luck with your layering I would add an event handler to the "IsEngagedChanged" and "ErrorOccurred" Events for further debug.

Comment: I checked all controller I use. And also cross check with different background color to all control. It's not work.